# in swiftUI not see "Launch Screen"

Tags: swiftui, launch-screen

**
I have seen several topics on the subject but I cannot resolve.
I created a "launchScreen - Storyboard" file and set general - app icons and launch screen - launch screen file.
I set "is initial view controller" in the launch screen.
I set in info Launchscreen:
imagename -> name of the image to load.
background color -> name of the color to load.
image respects safe area insets -> YES.
But anyway when I start the simulator, it loads me the content view directly.

Comment: Are you setting the view controller class name in the launch screen storyboard? It would be better if you spent a little more time rephrasing your questions to make it more clear. Better questions lead to better answers

Comment: in swiftUI by default there is no launchScreen. so I made file -> new -> file and in the user interface I created Launch Screen. then I did the above steps, but the launch screen is not visible. it shows me the content of the content view directly.